# Ansible :- list sub directories in a dir & use each dir name as a variable.

Tags: automation, ansible, devops

I want to list all sub-directories in a parent directory then use each directory name a seperate variable in ansible for further action.

Comment: _"I want to..."_ This is not how to ask questions at SO! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that it is in general not possible to use file names as Ansible variables. A file name can contain characters, which are illegal in a variable name.

Also keep in mind, that a file could have the same name as an already defined variable. It is better to prefix the variable to avoid collisions.

The following example filters for valid file names and prefixes the variable names.

```
---
- hosts: test1

  tasks:

    - find:
        path: /etc
        file_type: file
        use_regex: yes
        patterns: "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$"
        recurse: no
      register: files

    - set_fact:
        "my_{{ item | basename }}": "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ files.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"

    - debug: var=my_passwd
    - debug: var=my_hosts
```